# test the existence of property in a deep object structure

Tags: javascript

In javascript, lets say I want to access a property deep in an object, for example:

entry.mediaGroup[0].contents[0].url

At any point along that structure, a property may be undefined (so mediaGroup may not be set).

What is a simple way to say:

```
if( entry.mediaGroup[0].contents[0].url ){
   console.log( entry.mediaGroup[0].contents[0].url )
}
```

without generating an error? This way will generate an undefined error if any point along the way is undefined.

My solution

```
if(entry) && (entry.mediaGroup) && (entry.MediaGroup[0]) ...snip...){
   console.log(entry.mediaGroup[0].contents[0].url)
}
```

which is pretty lengthy. I am guessing there must be something more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/*decend through an object tree to a specified node, and return it.
  If node is unreachable, return undefined. This should also work with arrays in the tree.                                                                                               
  Examples:                                                                                                                                                                            
    var test1 = {a:{b:{c:{d:1}}}};                                                                                                                                            
    console.log(objectDesend(test1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));                                                                                                                
    var test2 = {a:{b:{c:1}}};     //will fail to reach d                                                                                                                                         
    console.log(objectDesend(test2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
*/
var objectDescend = function(){
    var obj = arguments[0];
    var keys = arguments;
    var cur = obj;                                                                                                                                                        
    for(var i=1; i<keys.length; i++){                                                                                                                                     
        var key = keys[i];                                                                                                                                                
        var cur = cur[key];                                                                                                                                               
        if(typeof(cur)=='undefined')                                                                                                                                      
            return cur;                                                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                                                     
    return cur;                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                         

var test1 = {a:{b:{c:{d:1}}}};                                                                                                                                            
console.log(objectDescend(test1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));                                                                                                                
var test2 = {a:{b:{c:1}}};                                                                                                                                              
console.log(objectDescend(test2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
```

So this will return either the value you are looking for, or undefined since that value doesn't exist. It won't return false, as that may actually be the value you are looking for (d:false).

In my code base, I add Object.prototype.descend, so I can do test1.descend('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'). This will only work in ECMAScript 5 (IE>=9) since you need to make it so your function doesn't appear in enumerations.  For more info:
[Add a method to Object primative, but not have it come up as a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642231/add-a-method-to-object-primative-but-not-have-it-come-up-as-a-property)

Here is my code for that:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'descend', {
    value: function(){
        var keys = arguments;
        var cur = this;
        for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
            var key = keys[i];
            var cur = cur[key];
            if(typeof(cur)=='undefined')
                return cur;
        }
        return cur;
    }
});



var test1 = {a:{b:{c:{d:false}}}};
//this will return false, which is the value of d                                                                                   
console.log(test1.descend('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));                                                                                                                       
var test2 = {a:{b:{c:1}}};
//undefined since we can't reach d.                                                                                                
console.log(test2.descend(test2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
```

Comment: `var cur = cur[key]; `  var is not needed

Answer (score 7):

This is a very lazy way to do it, but it meets the criteria for many similar situations:

```
try {
  console.log(entry.mediaGroup[0].contents[0].url);
} catch (e) {}
```

This should not be done on long code blocks where other errors may potentially be ignored, but should be suitable for a simple situation like this.

Comment: Nice, this looks like the shortest way to test. I am now using this, but there is something that feels wrong about using a try to test this sort of thing.

Comment: There are more important criteria than "shorter", such as robustness, performance, maintainability, debug-ability, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Your current solution is probably as good as you can get, as mVChr says, try..catch is just lazy here. It's probably far less effient and has nothing to recommend it other than perhaps being easier to type (but not significantly so) and it'll be harder to debug as it silently hides errors.

The real issue is the very long "reference worm" created by attempting such access. An alternative to the original that at least reduces the number of property lookups is:

```
var o;
if ( (o = entry       ) &&
     (o = o.mediaGroup) &&
     (o = o[0]        ) &&
     (o = o.contents  ) &&
     (o = o[0]        )) {
  alert(o.url);
}
```

But I expect you won't like that.

If you have many such deep access paths, you might like to create a function to do the access and return the last object on success or some other vaule on failure. For failure, you could also have it return the last non-falsey object on the path.

```
// Create test object
var entry = {};
entry.mediaGroup = [{
  contents: [{url: 'url'}]
}];

// Check that it "works" 
// alert(entry.mediaGroup[0].contents[0].url);


// Deep property access function, returns last object
// or false
function deepAccess(obj) {

  var path = arguments;
  var i = 0, iLen = path.length;
  var o = path[i++];  // o is first arg
  var p = path[i++];  // p is second arg

  // Go along path until o[p] is falsey
  while (o[p]) {
    o = o[p];
    p = path[i++];
  }

  // Return false if didn't get all the way along
  // the path or the last non-falsey value referenced
  return (--i == iLen) && o;
}

// Test it    
var x = deepAccess(entry, 'mediaGroup','0','contents','0');
alert(x && x.url);  // url

var x = deepAccess(entry, 'mediaGroup','1','contents','0');
alert(x && x.url);  // false
```

Comment: I think your first solution is the best. It sucks to write that kind of code, but honestly the alternatives aren't better imo.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably 3-4 different questions along this vein, and four times as many answers.  None of them really satisfied me, so I made my own, and I'll share it.

**This function is called "deepGet".**

*Example:*

`deepGet(mySampleData, "foo.bar[2].baz", null);`

Here is the full code:

```
function deepGet (obj, path, defaultValue) {

    // Split the path into components
    var a = path.split('.');

    // If we have just one component left, note that for later.
    var last = (a.length) === 1;

    // See if the next item is an array with an index
    var myregexp = /([a-zA-Z]+)(\[(\d+)\])+/; // matches:  item[0]
    var match = myregexp.exec(a[0]);

    // Get the next item
    var next;
    if (match !== null) {
        next = obj[match[1]];
        if (next !== undefined) {
            next = next[match[3]];
        }
    } else {
        next = obj[a[0]];
    }

    if (next === undefined || next === null) {
        // If we don't have what we want, return the default value
        return defaultValue;
    } else {
        if (last) {
            // If it's the last item in the path, return it
            return next; 
        } else { 
            // If we have more items in the path to go, recurse
            return deepGet (next, a.slice(1).join("."), defaultValue); 
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7quzmjh8/2/

I was inspired by these two things:

http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/making-deep-property-access-safe-in-javascript.html
http://jsfiddle.net/wxrzM/1/

Hopefully this is useful to someone out there :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple function for playing around with deep object properties:

```
getProperty = function(path) {
    try {
        return eval(path);
    }
    catch (e) {
        return undefined;
    }
};
```

Here's an example:

```
var test = {a:{b:{c:"success!"}}};

alert(getProperty('test.c.c'));
// undefined

alert(getProperty('test.a.b.c'));
// success!
```

Comment: bad idea overall. the `eval` function should be avoided as it cannot be optimised. This also gives no advantage but by replacing it by an explicit path, except that it is in a function.

Comment: Good point about optimization. What would you consider to be the best approach to answer the original question?

Comment: A way so you can check the structure of the object. This http://disnetdev.com/contracts.js/#object-contracts is a very good approach for that, but most don't need/want the overhead contracts-js gives you. But in fact, you could build something simple that works similar for checking the structure of an object. Sample (not completely implemented): https://gist.github.com/froginvasion/3c10c77531751ea3f497

Answer (score -1):

Here's the one i have been using for a while

```
   var obj = { a: { b: [
                        { c: {d: 'XYZ'} }
                    ] } };

    // working

    obj.a.b[0].c.d = null;
    console.log('value:'+getProperty(obj, 'a.b[0].c.d', 'NOT-AVAILABLE')); // value:null

    obj.a.b[0].c.d = 'XYZ';
    console.log('value:'+getProperty(obj, 'a.b[0].c.d', 'NOT-AVAILABLE')); // value:XYZ
    console.log('value:'+getProperty(obj, 'a.b[0].c.d.k.sds', 'NOT-AVAILABLE')); // value:NOT-AVAILABLE

    obj.a.b[0].c = null;
    console.log('value:'+getProperty(obj, 'a.b[0].c.d', 'NOT-AVAILABLE'));  // value:NOT-AVAILABLE


    // will not work
    //console.log('v:'+getProperty(obj, 'a.b["0"].c.d'));
```

Here's the function

```
function getProperty(obj, str, defaultValue){

    var props = str.split('.').map(function(prop){
        var arrAccessRegEx = /(.*)\[(.*)\]/g;
        if (arrAccessRegEx.test(prop)){
            return prop.split(arrAccessRegEx).filter(function(ele){return ele!=''; });
        } else {
            var retArr = [];
            retArr.push(prop);
            return retArr
        };
    });

    //console.log(props);

    for(var i=0;i<props.length;i++){
        var prop = props[i][0];

        //console.log('prop:'+prop);

        if (obj === null) return defaultValue;

        obj = obj[prop];

        if (obj === undefined) return defaultValue;

        if (props[i].length == 2){
            var idx = props[i][1];
            if (!(obj instanceof Array)) return defaultValue;
            if (idx < obj.length ){
                obj = obj[idx];
                if (obj === undefined) return defaultValue;
            }
        }

    } // for each item in split

    return obj;
}
```