# Add a method to Object primative, but not have it come up as a property

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

Object has `Object.toString`, a method that you can call on any object. When iterating through the property list, or, just doing a console.log(obj), you will not see toString come up as a property of an object. It is hidden.

I want to add a new method on to the Object primitive, using Object.prototype.myMethod. I do not however want it to come up every time I iterate through an object. I would like it hidden.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with ECMAScript 5's [`defineProperty` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'myMethod', {
    value: function() {
        // your function
    },
    enumerable: false // default is already `false`
});
```

Obviously this does not work in browsers that don't support ES5 (especially IE8 and earlier).

Comment: So then `Object.toString()` is a special feature of the language?

Comment: @Mrchief: Depends what you mean with special. It is a method that is defined in the specification: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.2.4.2

Comment: Special in the sense that prior to ES5, this is not something you can do on your own, it comes baked in with the language.

Comment: @Mrchief: Yes. I mean, there have always been this internal attributes but they have not been modifiable for custom methods before.

Comment: This solution worked great for me (I am doing this under node.js)