# Safe way to check deep objects that's readable?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at a codebase and unfortunately saw a lot of code like:

```
if (module && module.foo && module.foo.bar && module.foo.bar.baz)
```

I started googling to see if there was a lib or something to make this tolerable; didn't find but I'm still sure exists somewhere). I wrote this quickly but sort of hate it since it's ugly to pass in the root object and a string to split on '.'; was hoping for something better:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>safe tests</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function assert(condition, desc) {
           var d = document, li = d.createElement("li");
           li.className = condition ? "pass" : "fail";
           li.appendChild(d.createTextNode(desc));
           d.getElementById('results').appendChild(li);
       }
   </script>
   <style type="text/css">
       #results li.pass { color: green; }
       #results li.fail{ color: red; }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="results"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
function safe(root, s) {
    var split = s.split('.'), checked = root;
    for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (checked[split[i]]) {
           checked = checked[split[i]];
           continue;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
var foo = {
    bar: {
        baz: {
            qux: 'yippie!'
        }
    }
}
assert(safe(foo, 'bar'), "finds first sub object");
assert(safe(foo, 'bar.baz'), "finds first and then second sub object");
assert(safe(foo, 'bar.baz.qux'), "finds first, second, third, sub object");
assert(!safe(foo, 'bar.baz.qux.NOT'), "rejects if not defined (end)");
assert(!safe(foo, 'NOPE.baz.qux.NOT'), "rejects if not defined (front)");
assert(!safe(foo, 'bar.NO.baz'), "rejects if not defined (middle)");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions or libraries that already handle this that are lean?

Comment: from what I can see, your snippet could fail with:
var foo = {
    bar: {
        baz: {
            qux: false
        }
    }
}
Aside from that it seems to do the work. @Slukehart 's solution looks nice too.

Comment: @eburgos that's a good point on last prop if contains false; qux: false ... this is easily fixed; but my issue is the general ugliness and that I'd have to do myself (instead of using an existing solution). It seems like this is a common issue that should be solved already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the method:

```
if (module && module.foo && module.foo.bar && module.foo.bar.baz)
```

still remains the best to test for a valid path in a object. That said, I think you could use something like that to test a valid object path:

```
var safeObjectPath = function safeObjectPath( object, properties ) {
    var path = [],
        root = object,
        prop;

    if ( !root ) {
        // if the root object is null we immediately returns
        return false;
    }

    if ( typeof properties === 'string' ) {
        // if a string such as 'foo.bar.baz' is passed,
        // first we convert it into an array of property names
        path = properties ? properties.split('.') : [];
    } else {
        if ( Object.prototype.toString.call( properties ) === '[object Array]' ) {
            // if an array is passed, we don't need to do anything but
            // to assign it to the internal array
            path = properties;
        } else {
            if ( properties ) {
                // if not a string or an array is passed, and the parameter
                // is not null or undefined, we return with false
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // if the path is valid or empty we return with true (because the
    // root object is itself a valid path); otherwise false is returned.
    while ( prop = path.shift() ) {
        // Before it was used an if..else statement only, but it
        // could generate an exception in case of inexistent
        // object member. We can fix it using a try..catch
        // statement. Thanks to @xecute for the contribution!
        try {
            if ( prop in root ) {
                root = root[prop];
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch(e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The function will accept a **string** or an **array** as `properties` value. Internally the parameter is converted to an array and tested for the path.

Properties can be specified as `'foo.bar.baz'` or `['foo','bar','baz']`.

To test for a valid path:

```
safeObjectPath( module )
safeObjectPath( module, 'foo.bar.baz' )
safeObjectPath( module, [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ] )
```

Please, note that the first form (the one without `properties` parameter) will returns `true` (if passed root object is valid, of course) since that `module` is a valid path (the root).

It's possibile to test it with this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/begck/).

---

<del>I believe it would be possibile to think at a recursive and/or bindable version, too.</del>

**EDIT:** I've extended this answer with [a more detailed analysis](https://coderwall.com/p/cvbgia) in my article published on  Coderwall.

Here's a [performance test](http://jsperf.com/isobjectdefinedproto) built by [@xecute](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958632/xecute) (Thanks again for your efforts).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/828197/ragnarokkr thanks for your suggestions. >> still remains the best to test for a valid path in a object ... can you go further in to why you feel this is best way?

Comment: you're welcome @Rob. It's more a matter of personal taste, but I think that in a situation which requires to validate the effectivness of a path inside an object, the direct form inside an IF statement still remains the best mode, because it's immediately clear what the developer want to do in that moment (using a function, even if pretty clear, requires to figure out what that function will does, anyway), and the computing time required to the test it will be shorter than the one required by a function (due to the IF's short-circuit evaluation, and the minor overload for the processing).

Comment: @Rob, sorry comment too long.. That said, specific and complex cases aside, I think that when we find ourselves in having to do with so complex and nested objects, probably it's better to think again to that structure and how to refactor it.

Comment: Thanks Ragnarokkr - I liked kennebec function too but you did account for Strings and Arrays; somewhat arbitrarily giving you the best answer ;)

Comment: Thanks. Glad to have been helpful @Rob. :)

Comment: @Ragnarokkr "foo.bar.taz.caz.saz" wasn't working so I added try catch, here is : http://jsfiddle.net/begck/4/

Comment: @xecute good point! I didn't take in account the chance to check for non-object roots. I fixed my code examples. Thanks!

Comment: @Ragnarokkr ;) Here I made an test for your function, and I have to say, it's really working well! : http://jsperf.com/isobjectdefinedproto

Comment: @xecute well, it's really a good work! Thanks for your effort in testing its performance. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

```
function safe(str, O){
    var seg= str.split('.');
    O= O || window;
    while(O && seg.length) O= O[seg.shift()];
    return O;
}
```

same idea as your code, most useful for finding code modules that need loading .

Comment: +1. Generally speaking you want to do Object first for your parameters.

With that said, this converts very nicely to a LoDash mixin: `_.mixin({ 'getDeep': function (O, str){ var seg= str.split('.'); O= O || window; while(O && seg.length) O= O[seg.shift()]; return O; }});`

Answer (score 1):

Have you come across this snippet ([as referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208533/test-the-existence-of-property-in-a-deep-object-structure))?

```
/*decend through an object tree to a specified node, and return it.
If node is unreachable, return undefined. This should also work with arrays in the tree.                                                                                               
Examples:                                                                                                                                                                            
  var test1 = {a:{b:{c:{d:1}}}};                                                                                                                                            
  console.log(objectDesend(test1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));                                                                                                                
  var test2 = {a:{b:{c:1}}};     //will fail to reach d                                                                                                                                         
  console.log(objectDesend(test2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
*/

var objectDescend = function () {
    var obj = arguments[0];
    var keys = arguments;
    var cur = obj;

    for (var i=1; i<keys.length; i++) {                                                                                                                                     
        var key = keys[i];                                                                                                                                                
        var cur = cur[key];                                                                                                                                               
        if(typeof(cur)=='undefined')                                                                                                                                      
            return cur;                                                                                                                                                   
    }      

    return cur;                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                         

var test1 = {a:{b:{c:{d:1}}}};                                                                                                                                            
console.log(objectDescend(test1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));                                                                                                                
var test2 = {a:{b:{c:1}}};                                                                                                                                              
console.log(objectDescend(test2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
```

Comment: this is essentially the same logic as what I'm suggesting (for all intensive purposes) + you require multiple varargs; not really what I'm looking for but thanks!

Comment: Your right, maybe a functional approach... I'll think on this tonight, it has been irritating me too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if`, you can use a silent `try ... catch`:

```
try {
    var baz = module.foo.bar.baz;
    ...
} catch (e) { }
```

This will drop out on the first line if `module`, `foo` or `bar` are missing.

The disadvantage is that this won't catch any **other errors** that are thrown from within the block.