# does deep object exist control in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

```
var session = {}
session.query = {}
session.query.username = "foo";

if( session.query.username )
    console.log('surname exists');

if( session.query2.username )
    console.log('surname exists');
```

this code throws this exception: "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'query2' of undefined**"

searched in stackoverflow and found this solution :

```
...
if( session && session.query2 && session.query2.username )
    console.log('surname exists')
```

but this is very long and I have very nested object's controls, so I can't use this method. Is there any short method that I can use?

Comment: you could give a try to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15399878/828197) and read a little bit more detailed [analysis](https://coderwall.com/p/cvbgia) of that answer.

Comment: Another approach is wrapping this check into `try-catch` block. But the point is, you shouldn't try to avoid structuring the code so that this type of check is necessary.

Comment: @Ragnarokkr I really couldn't find it on Google Search or Stackoverflow Search. I think it'll answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @xecute. Glad to have been helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safe way to check deep objects that's readable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399305/safe-way-to-check-deep-objects-thats-readable)

Answer (score 0):

This can work for you:

```
try {
    session.query.username &&
    console.log('Username exists');
} catch () {
    console.log('Username does not exist');
}
```

In case of very deep paths (or when you need to test many of them) it can be shorter.