# Checking for object and property existance

Tags: javascript, node.js

I work with mongodb on a regular basis and before accessing a specific property from a query result, I write an existence check that often looks like this:

```
if(result && result.subObject1 && result.subObject1.property) { ... }
```

This is safest way to check the result stream, or any other object that I'm receiving, that I know of.

This works just fine, its just that most of the time I think to myself, "There's probably a better way to do this", there is.

I looked at a few related posts but none of them really addresses this, especially when dealing with (possibly) deeply nested objects.

Comment: There is not really a more efficient way, but you can use a function to shorten a bit the check. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208533/test-the-existence-of-property-in-a-deep-object-structure

Comment: Just as an FYI, this is built-in to [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) (look for "The Existential Operator").

Answer (score 1):

Avoid truth/false checks on data values themselves.

E.g.

request body : `data : { temperature : -128, level : 42 }` etc.

server validation : `data must be sent and have temperature value set`

validation code : `if(data && data.temperature){//ok}else{//invalid input}`

The above validation code will reject 0 and negative temperature values as well, while server's actual validation motive was to ensure temperature value is always set.

Hence checks should be clearly and separately defined:

`function exists(val){ return val !== undefined && val !== null; }`

`function isNumber(val){ return !isNan(val); }`

and combinations of these checks should be used.

For more robust checks, use modules like [validator](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js).

As far as deep checks are concerned, you will need to define a full and proper [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html) first and then run a [schema validator](https://github.com/natesilva/jayschema) on it.

Comment: If a property was `0`, you'd probably not try to access a property on it…

Comment: @Bergi I was referring to value not property. If server expects a number value for say "amount" key, and receives "amount":"0", then `if(data.amount)` will be falsy, and server assumes data didn't had "amount" value at all.

Comment: But you wouldn't need to test for that. Just `if (data) { … data.amount … }`